# grails asset pipeline: how to find image url dynamically in javascript (with knockout)

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline

What's the best practice when you have a number of image assets that might change on a page (because you're creating part of the DOM on the fly with Knockout, Angular, whatever) and you need to put together the URL?

For simplicity sake, suppose I have a set of images that represent progress from 0 to 100 percent, and I want to insert a chunk of code that effectively does something like this:

```
var oImg=document.createElement("img");
var percent = calculateSomeOtherThingHere();
oImg.setAttribute('src', 'SOME URL GOES HERE%/pctImage' + percent);
document.body.appendChild(oImg);
```

Additionally, how do I ensure that the asset pipeline understands that I might need any of those images (from pctImage0 to pctImage100) when rendering the page?

Any clues anyone? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using grails 3.x with the assets plugin, you could insert this code in the view (or in the layout) gsp file:

```
<g:javascript>
    var grailsRes = {
        pctImage1 : '${assetPath(src: '1.jpg')}',
        pctImage2 : '${assetPath(src: '2.jpg')}',
        pctImage3 : '${assetPath(src: '3.jpg')}',
        //...
        pctImage98 : '${assetPath(src: '98.jpg')}',
        pctImage99 : '${assetPath(src: '99.jpg')}',
        pctImage100 : '${assetPath(src: '100.jpg')}'
    };
</g:javascript>
```

Then, change your javascript code to something like this:

```
var oImg=document.createElement("img");
var percent = calculateSomeOtherThingHere();
oImg.setAttribute('src', grailsRes['pctImage' + percent]);
document.body.appendChild(oImg);
```

For a simpler code you could use an array with index access.

Check the [grails assets plugin documentation here](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking).